# How can I configure execution start between dependent jobs?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins server is set up with two jobs A and B say.

Job A is triggered from changes in subversion, runs unit tests and if successful, creates a WAR and deploys it to another environment.

If Job A succeeds, then Job B triggers. This job runs tests against the deployed WAR.

The problem is that the deployment process takes a while and the WAR is not ready in time for when Job B starts and tries to use it.

I'm looking for ideas on how to delay Job B until the WAR is up and running.

Is there a way, once Job B is triggered to wait for x seconds? I really don't want to put it into the tests in Job B if I can avoid it.

Thanks

Comment: maybe job B could do the deployement based on the war generated by  job A (that would be stored in the lastSuccessfulBuild's artifacts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely a way for a job to wait - just put `sleep` into the first shell build step. Alternatively, you can set 'Quiet period' - it's in *Advanced Project Options* when you create a build.

That, however, is a band-aid solution to be employed only if other approaches fail. You may try the following: if there is a way to make the deployment process (that job A triggers) right before it finishes to touch a file that Jenkins has access to, then you can use [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin). See use case 3 there.

Comment: thanks, goof overview of the available options. Have set a sleep for the time  being but am going to look into the FSTrigger Plugin as it looks really useful for this and other situations.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to make this work would be to make job A not complete until the deployment is successful, e.g. by testing for a valid response from the URL of the deployed web app.  [This blog post](http://blog.synyx.de/2011/10/testing-webapp-startup-on-jenkins-with-maven-tomcat-and-web-driver/) describes one way to do that.